# Magento 2 : Increase sold count after order status completes

Tags: magento2, product, orders, products, order-status

I'm new to Magento 2.
I want to show the sold count of product only after the order was complete.

I have used this code to display count.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$sku = $_product->getSku(); 
$objectModelManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance ();
$soldproduct = $objectModelManager->get('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection')->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->getFirstItem(); 
$soldnumber = $soldproduct->getOrderedQty();
?> <div class="sold_count"><b>Sold Count: </b> <?php echo (int)$soldnumber;?> </div>
```

But for every order placement the count is increasing.But I want show the count of products whose status was completed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

we added code above but not showing (magento 2.3.4)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.We can filter based on the order state 'complete'(**addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')**)

```
$soldproduct = $objectModelManager->get('Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection')->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')->getFirstItem();
```